# How to create a page with a form programmatically in WP?

Tags: plugin-development

I made some research and found a way how to create custom pages using content (post) types. However, I do not want to create a new post type, I just want to create a page having a certain URL (`/form`) with a form on it. I was not able to find how to do it without custom post types. Can someone show me the correct direction? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why can't you just go to _Pages > Add New_, create a page called "Form" and put your form on it? If you needs something more than that you'll need to be more specific with your question.

Comment: Because I want to do it programmatically. It's in the title. I do not need to explain why do I need to do it that way.

Comment: Can someone clear up what is wrong with this question? It is perfectly clear what I want to achieve (create a page programmatically, not via admin interface, obviously - it's right in the title!) and I also made my effort to try to find it out, however, no luck. An accepted answer bellow proves that the question is perfectly alright. Obviously, most of the WP "developers" just know how to click mouse and install plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **wp_insert_post()** function with '**after_theme_setup**' action hook to programatically create pages. Here is a short example,

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'create_form_page' );
function create_form_page(){

    $title = 'Form';
    $slug = 'form';
    $page_content = ''; // your page content here
    $post_type = 'page';

    $page_args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $page_content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_slug' => $slug
    );

    if(post_exists($title) === 0){
        $page_id = wp_insert_post($page_args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install a form plugin. Contact form 7 is a good one :
 https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Create a form using the plugin.

Create a normal WP page and add your form to it by pasting the contact-form-7 shortcode into the page.

Comment: Noticed the word "programmatically" in the question title?

Comment: So "How to programmatically create a page with a form in WP?" not "How to create a page with a form programmatically in WP?"

Comment: A bit more like "programmatically as in using lines of codes instead of clicking things in a graphical user interface". Installing a plugin, using the graphical user interface of said plugin, then copy pasting stuff in yet ever more user interfaces is not programmatic, at least in regard to its general usage.